# Should I develop a new app that targets older versions of iOS or use the older Facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a new iOS app and would like to add facebook integration. One issue that has come up is whether we should stick with Facebook 3.0 or go with Facebook 3.1. It is my understanding that Facebook 3.1 would require iOS 6 (Is this correct?). Honestly, if 20% of people still have iOS 5, it's probably best for us to stay with that version. Are there any strong opinions on FB 3.0 vs FB 3.1 at this point? Even simple 3 or 3.1 is fine.

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was [a post a year or so ago by Matt Gemmell about this](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/12/05/latest-version/), talking about the benefits and downsides to developing for an older version of iOS. His basic argument for latest-only boils down to:

- Less hassle
- Less code
- Better customers
- Free marketing

According to [Marco Arment's statistics](http://www.marco.org/2011/11/30/more-ios-device-and-os-version-stats-from-instapaper) from Instapaper, nearly 50% of people were using iOS4+ within 50 days of its release, and 98% were using it within 9 months. So, for an existing app, you may need to support older versions for 9 months or so, **but for a brand new app, go for the latest and greatest**.

Comment: thx Tim for answer and references

Answer (score 0):

Facebook SDK 3.1 supports both 4.3+ from their site: "Seamless Facebook Login across iOS versions: Lets your app work seamlessly on all iOS versions 4.3+ and easily integrates with the native login support in iOS 6." - https://developers.facebook.com/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3.1/

It uses the os integration only if you have ios6 but falls back gracefully.

Comment: thx Edwin, looks like 3.1 might be better